# SQL ultimo registro con un valor determinado

Tags: sql

Hola tengo una tabla con una serie de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito identificar si algún interruptor se quedó sin cerrar, como en este caso el interruptor A, para el ejemplo es sencillo pero para una multitud de datos donde cada interruptor se puede abrir y cerrar muchas veces me resulta complejo, si alguien me puede ayudar les agradecería

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] y mostrá lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Editá la pregunta y escribí la/s consulta/s que probaste. Y mientras, leete el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).